# If $(G,*)$ is a group and $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n \in G$, prove that$(a_1*a_2*\ldots*a_n)^{-1} = a_n^{-1}*\ldots*a_1^{-1}$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, inverse

If $(G,*)$ is a group and $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n \in G$, prove that
$(a_1*a_2*\ldots*a_n)^{-1} = a_n^{-1}*\ldots*a_1^{-1}$.

**Attempt:**
For the simplify and the convenience,
write $a*b=ab$.

I'll prove it by induction on $n$.

Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n \in G$.
Let $P(n)$ be the statement:
$(a_1*a_2*\ldots*a_n)^{-1} = a_n^{-1}*\ldots*a_1^{-1}$.

**Base Case:**
Clearly $P(1)$ is true since $(a_1)^{-1} = a_1^{-1}$. (Is it enough? What if I take $P(1)$ and $P(2)$ for the base case?)

**Inductive Step:**
Assume that $P(k)$ is true. That is,
$(a_1*a_2*\ldots*a_n)^{-1} = a_n^{-1}*\ldots*a_1^{-1}$.
To show that $P(k+1)$ is also true, here it is:
\begin{align*}
(a_1a_2\ldots a_{k+1})^{-1} &=
((a_1a_2\ldots a_k)a_{k+1})^{-1} \\
&= (a_{k+1})^{-1}(a_1a_2\ldots a_k)^{-1} \\
&= a_{k+1}^{-1}(a_k^{-1}a_{k-1}^{-1}\ldots a_1^{-1}) \\
&=a_{k+1}^{-1}a_k^{-1}a_{k-1}^{-1}\ldots a_1^{-1}
\end{align*}
as desired.

Hence, $(a_1*a_2*\ldots*a_n)^{-1} = a_n^{-1}*\ldots*a_1^{-1}$ for all
$a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n \in G$. $\Box$

Is the approach above true?

Comment: You need to include $P(2)$ in the base case, because you _use_ $P(2)$ in the induction step! (So if $P(2)$ is not already known the inductive step from $P(1)$ to $P(2)$ is circular...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich So, in the base case is $P(1)$ and $P(2)$ right now, isn't it?

Comment: Without $P(2)$ you are following exactly the same argument as [this](https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/falseProofs/sameAge.html) wrong proof.

Comment: @Bumblebee Okay, got it. Thanks yow!

Comment: Iteratively apply socks and shoes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this looks good with $P(2)$ which you use implicitly in your inductive step, if you're really trying to be exacting in the amount of detail, you may want to be explicit in you use of the base case and the inductive hypothesis in your inductive step, but I think almost anyone who read this would have no problem with it.

Comment: Thanks Sir. What about I take two value in base case, Sir?

Comment: I mean, $P(1)$ and $P(2)$? For $P(2): (a_1a_2)^{-1} = a_2^{-1}a_1^{-1}$ by definition of the inverse of two non-identity elements in $G$.

Comment: No offence, but the answer given by OP is incomplete without $P(2).$

Comment: @Bumblebee None taken. To be honest I saw P(2) in OP's proof and for some reason thought they had included that that too. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

Your induction proof looks fine.

Alternatively, you can use uniqueness of inverses and just check that
$$
(a_1*\cdots*a_n)(a_n^{-1}*\cdots*a_1^{-1}) = e
$$
using associativity.